# What is the standard convention to maintain files in .NET MVC Framework?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

In MVC; Model, View and Controllers are standard folders.

But in best standard practice where do we put other external classes and folders like.

- All repo classes
- Mapper Classes or Folder
- And all other helper classes …………….

I know it can be maintain anywhere as per convenient. But just want to know is there any Standard convention?

Will appreciate your answer or suggest me any standard blog url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends from Project to Project.

But as a good practice, if it is a considerably large project you can have one single `class library` to manage most external folders. One of the common practice these days with `MVC` is `repository pattern`.

> You can check the [nopCommerce](http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#README.md) architecture which will give you a good idea about `repository pattern` and architecture in general. If you do want to implement repository pattern you can still get some idea about the standard convention.